# Prove that the relation $\leq$ on the braid group $B_n$ is anti symmetric.

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, braid-groups

For $A,B$ in the braid group $B_n$, we define $A \leq B$ if $B=CAC'$ for some $C$ and $C'$ in $B_n^{+}$, i.e., $C$ and $C'$ are positive words. We need to show that this relation is anti symmetric. This has been directly stated in papers regarding braid groups but I wanted to prove it. To show $\leq$ is anti symmetric, we need to prove that $A \leq B$ and $B \leq A$ implies $A=B$. Now, if $A \leq B$, then $B= CAC'$ and if $B \leq A$ we get $A=DBD'$ for positive words $C,C',D,D'$. This gives us $A=DCAC'D'$. I directly concluded that $DC$ and $C'D'$ would be identity braids but it is not very clear why, even though $DC$ and $C'D'$ are positive braids. Please help, I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell: B_n \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ be the abelianization. Note that $\ell$ is a homomorphism. More concretely: generating elements $\sigma_i$ get mapped to $1$ by $\ell$ (and their inverses to $-1$). So
$$\ell (DCAC'D') = \ell (D) + \ell (C) + \ell (A) + \ell (C') + \ell (D').$$
Since positive braids have non-negative length, it follows that if $\ell (DCAC'D') = \ell (A)$, that 
$$\ell (C) = \ell (C') = \ell (D) = \ell (D') = 0,$$
in other words, that the positive braids $C, C', D$, and $D'$ are all equal to the identity braid.

Comment: But l(AB)<=L(A)+l(B) when the codomain is B_n, and the equality holds only when the domain is the semi group of poitive words. And here A and B need not be positive braids.

Comment: I mean L(aa^{-1}) is 0 but L(a)=L(a^{-1})=1. Hence, 0<= 1+1 = 2.

Comment: Oh! I just saw that you defined it seperately. Thank you! Can you please suggest readings on Abelianization? I thought it was the same as length function on words, but it clearly isn't.

Comment: Just to make sure, on the positive braids(but not on the whole of B_n) this abelianisation coincides with the length function on words?

Comment: By the way, to see that $B_n/[B_n, B_n] \cong \mathbb Z$ you actually just need to prove that $\ell$ is a homomorphism and that all standard generators $\sigma_i$ are conjugate, both of which is easy to see.

Comment: The second part can be proven but (it does sound silly) I can't work on the homomorphism part. How do you prove l(ab)=l(a)+l(b),when a and b are arbitrary words? We only know what l does to its generators.

Comment: Do you know how to check whether maps $S \rightarrow G$ extend to group homomorphisms $\langle S \; | \; R \rangle \rightarrow G$ (group presentations)?

Comment: I shall read upon it, thanks for the nudge!

Comment: No problem. If my answer was helpful, you can mark it as the accepted one by clicking on the tick symbol.